# Can you identify this snake?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, herpetology, snake

On a walk through I’ON Swamp/Natural Forest in Mt. Pleasant, SC, we came upon this snake. We did not get too close for fear it may be poisonous.

It had a very dark brown/taupe exterior with almost a diamond shaped head. It had a reddish, orange belly. It was ~3-4’ in length and fairly large girth.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! Identifications questions must include one or more clear closeup photos of the organism (photos from multiple angles if possible) — photos must be uploaded (not links). Also note that personal medical questions (e.g. were we in danger) are not appropriate for this site. ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the help pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site. Thanks! 

Comment: there is a Yellow Belly Water snake here in TX that the book says is the same as a Red Belly Water snake in the east. Looks like a good possibility.

Comment: How do I upload a photo?

Comment: When you are making (or editing) a post there is a picture icon (looks like white mountains on a black background) in the tool bar at the top of the editing field that you click on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hard to tell without a clearer picture, but the size and color pattern seem to match the description for the [Plain-bellied Watersnake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nerodia_erythrogaster).

See for example the following picture from the [Virginia Herpetological Society](https://www.virginiaherpetologicalsociety.com/reptiles/snakes/red-bellied-water-snake/red-bellied_watersnake.php):
[image]

I assume from the location being in something called a swamp that the habitat (in and near slow moving bodies of water) also fits.

Comment: That’s it! That’s the same snake we saw on the trail. Thank you!

Comment: Great, glad I could help!